# How to specify schema for CSV file without using Scala case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading a CSV file into a DataFrame as below.

```
val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("dataframes").setMaster("local")
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val spark=SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.
  read.  
  format("org.apache.spark.csv").
  option("header", true).
  csv("/home/cloudera/Book1.csv")
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
```

How to change `age` column to be of type `Int`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is `inferSchema` option to automatically recognize the type of the variable by:

```
val df=spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", true) // <-- HERE
  .csv("/home/cloudera/Book1.csv")
```

`spark-csv` originally was an external library by databricks, but included in core spark from spark version 2.0 onwards. You can refer to documentation on the library's [github page](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features) to find the available options.

Answer (score 31):

Given `val spark=SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()` I *guess* you're using Spark 2.x.

---

First of all, please note that Spark 2.x has a native support for CSV format and as such does not require specifying the format by its long name, i.e. `org.apache.spark.csv`, but just `csv`.

```
spark.read.format("csv")...
```

Since you use `csv` operator, the CSV format is implied and so you can skip/remove `format("csv")`.

```
// note that I removed format("csv")
spark.read.option("header", true).csv("/home/cloudera/Book1.csv")
```

---

With that you have plenty of options, but I strongly recommend using a case class for...just the schema. See the last solution if you're curious how to do it in Spark 2.0.

### cast operator

You could use [cast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@cast(to:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) operator.

```
scala> Seq("1").toDF("str").withColumn("num", 'str cast "int").printSchema
root
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = true)
```

### Using StructType

You can also use your own hand-crafted schema with [StructType](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) and [StructField](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField) as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._    
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("str", StringType, true) :: 
  StructField("num", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)

scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = true)

val q = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  schema(schema).
  csv("numbers.csv")
scala> q.printSchema
root
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = true)
```

### Schema DSL

What I found quite interesting lately was so-called **Schema DSL**. The above schema built using `StructType` and `StructField` can be re-written as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(
  $"str".string ::
  $"num".int :: Nil) 
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = true)

// or even
val schema = new StructType().
  add($"str".string).
  add($"num".int)
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = true)
```

### Encoders

Encoders are so easy to use that it's hard to believe you could not want them, even only to build a schema without dealing with `StructType`, `StructField` and `DataType`.

```
// Define a business object that describes your dataset
case class MyRecord(str: String, num: Int)

// Use Encoders object to create a schema off the business object
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders    
val schema = Encoders.product[MyRecord].schema
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is use a UDF in this case :

**Step 1**: Make a udf that converts String to Int.

```
val stringToIntUDF = udf((value:String)=>value.toInt)
```

**Step 2** : Apply this UDF to the Column that you want to convert !

```
val updatedDF = df.withColumns("age",stringToIntUDF(df("age")))
updatedDF.printSchema
```

This should give you your desired result !

If you just want to infer your schema from the CSV file. Then @vdep solution seems to be doing the right thing !

```
val df=spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header",true)
  .option("inferSchema", "true") // <-- HERE
  .csv("/home/cloudera/Book1.csv")
```

Comment: Sorry I was not able to understand the question correctly I thought you just want to change the Age from String to Int and hence provided this solution !