# Add column names to data read from csv file without column names

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark with Scala.

I have a csv file that does not have column names in the first row. It's like this:

```
28,Martok,49,476
29,Nog,48,364
30,Keiko,50,175
31,Miles,39,161
```

The columns represent ID, name, age, numOfFriends.

In my Scala object, I am creating dataset using SparkSession from csv file as follows:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").csv("../myfile.csv")
df.printSchema()
```

When I run the program, the result is:

```
|-- _c0: integer (nullable = true)
|-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c2: integer (nullable = true)
|-- _c3: integer (nullable = true)
```

How can I add names to the columns in my dataset?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653813/how-to-specify-schema-for-csv-file-without-using-scala-case-class

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `toDF` to specify column names when reading the CSV file:

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").csv("../myfile.csv").toDF(
  "ID", "name", "age", "numOfFriends"
)
```

Or, if you already have the DataFrame created, you can rename its columns as follows:

```
val newColNames = Seq("ID", "name", "age", "numOfFriends")
val df2 = df.toDF(newColNames: _*)
```

Comment: can you provide a similar solution for java. I have a Dataset<Row> without headers and I want to select some columns not all from it.

Comment: @user812142, I haven't done much with Java on Spark.  Perhaps this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622909/6316508) might give some hints; if not, I would suggest posting a separate question with specific requirement and sample data.

Comment: Can you please provide a solution for the problem in PySpark?

Answer (score 1):

```
toDf
```

method can be used, where you can pass in the column name in spark java.

Example:

`Dataset<Row> rowsWithTitle = sparkSession.read().option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").csv("file").toDF("h1", "h2");`